# Fastest Way to capture images for Processing Picamera

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, camera-calibration

I'm using the picamera module with the pi to capture images and process them, one at a time, with the openCV library.

Currently I'm doing it like this at a 320x240 resolution (I can get about 30 images in the 20 seconds the loop runs);

```
while((now - start) < 20):
        image_count+=1
        try:
            stream = io.BytesIO()
            camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg', use_video_port = True)
```

The fastest a capture, process cycle can elapse is around 500ms - the majority of this time is spent in the capturing. Ideally I'd like to get around 10fps and a higher resolution images.

I've tried `capture_continious` before but when I convert my stream to a grey image it would break;

```
image= cv2.imdecode(stream, 1)
grey_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #continuous_capture breaks here.
```

I'd appreciate any insight into how to reduce this capture time as much as possible - ideally so that the processing becomes the limiting factor.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are capturing the frame and processing it within the same iteration, it makes sense that it is this slow. But there are other reasons for this behavior. You should provide a complete minimal example that reproduces this behavior.

Comment: there *must* be some kind of raw format, like 'bgr' or such. you probably don't need to encode/decode jpeg (which is quite expensive)

Comment: ah ok, yes you can encode as rgb like camera.capture('image.data', 'rgb') will try and implement it when I get a chance and see if it helps

Comment: although I think I'd have to alter my openCV processing in some way. the reccomended capture method is http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes1.html#capturing-to-an-opencv-object

Comment: since you only seem to need grayscale images, choosing 'yuv', and splitting off the 1st channel(y) might be the fastest approach

Comment: @berak could you provide an example?

Comment: i altered it to encode bgr imgages, reduces the capture time a little - about 50ms at 320x240 - but not enough. I tried yuv but it kept breaking so reverted to bgr